# What types of actions can I perform in Visual Studio using the vstfs:// protocol?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have reviewed the documentation at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130164(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130164%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and some related resources online, it seems that there are some things that you can do using the vstfs:// protocol which will open Visual Studio and perform a variety of different actions, but I cannot find a resource that lets me know the specific options available to me for the tooltype parameter.  I would like to know the specific list of actions available using this URL.

Specifically what I am hoping to be able to do is to open the VS TFS Merge UI using predefined parameters for source and target item specs and version specs using this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in time to earn a tumbleweed badge, I have found the answer to my question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tswaclienthyperlinkservice_methods.aspx

So it is easy to get these URLs but unfortunately not possible to get a URL which launches the merge tool (only the Diff tool).